# SQL query in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using php and Mysql and need help to display `UNIQUE` results for a price comparison.

My tables are:

tblItems

```
ID | SKU | Shop | Name | Size
1     S1   Shop1   A      S
2     S2   Shop1   B      M
3     S3   Shop1   C      L
4     S4   Shop2   A      S
```

tblProductFeed

```
ID | SKU | Shop | Price
1     S1   Shop1   12
2     S2   Shop1   14
3     S3   Shop1   15
4     S4   Shop2   11
```

The idea is a price comparison.

I want to compare all records where Size='S'. But I only want to get the lowest price from tblProductFeed, and I only want one record where the price is lowest.

My thoughts are like:

1. Get SKU, Shop and Name from tblItems where Size='S'
2. Compare matching rows in tblProductFeed where SKU and Shop are matching
3. Get the lowest price from tblProductFeed

Display only one `DISTINCT` Name from TblItems and with the lowest price

Results:

```
Name | Price
A       11
B       14
C       15
```

Maybe my idea is bad, please correct me.

Before I decided to scrap data and build to tables my sql was like this, might help to get some inspiration.

```
    SELECT tbl.* 
      FROM tblProductFeed tbl 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Size
                   , MIN(Price) MinPrice 
              FROM tblProductFeed 
             WHERE Size = '". $str ."' 
             GROUP BY Size) tbl1 
        ON tbl1.Size = tbl.Size 
     WHERE tbl1.MinPrice = tbl.Price;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this : to retrieve lowest price for data with size 'S'

```
select a.Name, a.Shop, b.Price as minprice from tblItems as a
inner join tblProductFeed as b on 
         a.id = b.id and
         a.SKU = b.SKU and
         a.Shop = b.shop
where a.size = 'S' and b.price in (select min(price) from tblProductFeed)
```

Result :

[image]

Or if you want to get all item with lowest price try this :

```
select name,min(price)minprice from 
(select a.id, a.SKU, b.shop, a.name, a.size, b.Price from tblItems as a
    inner join tblProductFeed as b on 
        a.id = b.id and
        a.SKU = b.SKU and
        a.Shop = b.shop
where b.price in (select min(price) from tblProductFeed group by price)) a
group by name
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I will test the code asap and get back.